# The "SCRAM-SHA-1" authentication mechanism requires libmongoc built with --enable-ssl

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

Getting error message while connecting to database using Laravel 5.4 and Mongodb 3.6

`The "SCRAM-SHA-1" authentication mechanism requires libmongoc built with --enable-ssl`

Its running fine in ubuntu 16.04 with same versions, but not in AWS Linux.

Installed LAMP [ php70, apach24 ] :

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Installed Mongodb [ 3.6 ] :

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/

Installed php-mongodb driver for php7:

```
sudo yum -y install php7-pear php70-devel gcc  // completed
sudo pecl7 install mongodb                     // completed 
sudo yum install openssl-devel                 // completed
```

php-mongodb driver installed and updated to php.ini, mongodb shows in phpinfo() as well.

we find there is libmongoc ssl disabled from phpinfo, Is that issue ?

[image]

How can we enable it ?

Comment: Check the PECL install again, you will likely see an error/warning along the lines of `Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries` If so ( or at least just to be sure ) then you should do something like `yum install openssl-devel` and run the install again. Look for errors/warnings in that step at any rate.

Comment: Instead of commenting every few minutes, how about you take the time to investigate the couple of things you were just told. Add your findings and any more valid output / errors to your question as you have them. If you read and follow what I said, then you will likely resolve it. If it's still unresolved, then adding the things you have done "step by step" to your question serves as a base for people to look and reproduce the issue, or point out what is missing.

Comment: @NeilLunn - got solution for this issue and posted the solution as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error, because of disabled `libmongoc SSL` and `libmongoc Crypto` from php-mongodb driver and enabled by following command.

```
sudo pecl7 config-set php_ini /etc/php.ini
```

After installing mongodb driver `sudo pecl7 install mongodb`, we should set the above.

now runs fine.

Answer (score 12):

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, PHP 7.2.7

I had to install some extra packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev
```

Then re-install mongodb:

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongodb
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Then check that SSL is enabled:

```
php -i | grep mongo
```

> /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini, 
>   mongodb
>   libmongoc bundled version => 1.11.0 
>   libmongoc SSL => enabled 
>   libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL 
>   libmongoc crypto => enabled 
>   libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto

Restart php:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who have the error on an **Alpine docker**. You must add in your **Dockerfile** :

`RUN apk add curl-dev openssl-dev`

instead of sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev

I used `RUN pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php.ini` too

Answer (score 4):

I get the same message using docker. I add to my Docker file

```
apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libssl-dev
```

and run

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved in CentOS 7

Remove mongodb extension:

```
pecl uninstall mongodb
```

Install openssl

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

Reinstall MongoDB extension again

```
pecl install mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Debian 9 module compillation fails with following error:

> configure: error: OpenSSL libraries and development headers could not
>   be found

If you have same error try following:

```
apt-get remove libssl-dev
apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, this command does everything on Debian 9 and php 7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Just restart Apache2 service afterwards