# Unable to fetch names of databases in MongoDB using PHP with command 'listdatabases'

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2, php-7.2

I have `PHP 7.2.30`, `MongoDB v4.2.8` and installed respective php-mongodb driver using `sudo pecl install mongodb` command. Screenshot to my `phpinfo()` is attached which contains details of `mongodb`.

[image]

Ultimate goal is to insert data into MongoDB from a webapplication. Initially, I am trying to list all the databases in my server. The code is as below:

```
<?php
  try {

      $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://sasia:password@52.65.114.76:27017");

      $listdatabases = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["listDatabases" => 1]);
      $res = $mng->executeCommand("assessment", new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["listDatabases" => 1]));

      $databases = current($res->toArray());

      foreach ($databases->databases as $el) {
          echo $el->name . "\n";
      }
  }
  catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
      $filename = basename(__FILE__);

      echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n";
      echo "It failed with the following exception:\n";

      echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
      echo "In file:", $e->getFile(), "\n";
      echo "On line:", $e->getLine(), "\n";
  }
?>
```

When I run this script, I am getting an error as `Exception:The SCRAM_SHA_1 authentication mechanism requires libmongoc built with ENABLE_SSL In file:/var/www/html/mongodb/stats.php On line:7`.

When I did some research, I found that `libmongoc SSL` has been `disabled` and that was the reason. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541607/the-scram-sha-1-authentication-mechanism-requires-libmongoc-built-with-enabl) post and tried enabling it. But still no luck. I am also not sure on what are the methods to work with the latest class `MongoDB\Driver\`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what have you done to build libmongoc with ssl support?

Comment: Provide build logs via a pastebin also.

Comment: After executing this command `sudo pecl install mongodb`, I executed `sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php.ini`. Reference is from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541607/the-scram-sha-1-authentication-mechanism-requires-libmongoc-built-with-enabl

Comment: Add build log to the question.